# Can we get together a group of C++ devs that work on Bitcoin apps?

Tags: development, c++, community

I've been trying to get into Bitcoin development and I've been having a horrible time. I tried multiple Bitcoin-related IRC channels for support but most responded with hostility, except for the libsecp256k1 channel whom at least tried to lend me a hand.

I can't seem to find any C++-specific, Bitcoin-specific spaces anywhere. At first I thought the search engines were to blame but now I'm starting to think forums truly are dead and everybody else's just  coding alone in caves. The closest thing I ran into is the Bitcoin Core dev IRC channel but apparently that's strictly for Bitcoin Core development. This Stack Exchange doesn't seem too dev-oriented either although I was still encouraged to post on here by IRC users.

Are any of you here? If so, what do you say we get a group together? I don't care what platform - if you program for Bitcoin in C++ please do say what platforms you use and see what we all have in common. IRC, Matrix, Discord, Session, whatever - we can have it all, just say which you like. I really REALLY need to get in touch with you... assuming you aren't all already dead. I'm truly friggin cold and alone here. Please. I refuse to think I can't even begin to learn this stuff because of a f***ing library dependency problem. Jeez.

Edit: removed references to libbitcoin. Turns out I didn't even need that for my use case.

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly you need to achieve, but a lot of things can be done just by calling APIs on nodes. There are also numerous libraries in many languages with a plethora of language bindings, possibly some of them would work for you even if they are not written in C++. Perhaps if you ask a little more specifically about the things you want to achieve, we can suggest some avenues how to achieve them even when we are not that plugged into libbitcoin.